# improving time efficiency of code

Tags: java

How can this code be edited to improve the time efficienc?

```
public static LLList intersect(LLList list1, LLList list2) {
    LLList inters = new LLList();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length(); i++) {
        Object item1 = list1.getItem(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list2.length(); j++) {
            Object item2 = list2.getItem(j);
            if (item2.equals(item1)) {
                inters.addItem(item2, inters.length());
                break;   // move onto the next item from list1
            }
        }
    }

    return inters;
}
```

Comment: Who said it can?

Comment: It is one of my assignments but I'm not sure how this can be simplified at all

Comment: Not clear whether these are linked lists, array lists or some other type.  But you could look at the `retainAll` method of the `LinkedList` class or of the `ArrayList` class to see how it's done there.

Comment: Also, if you know that these two lists are sorted into an equivalent order, you can use that fact to speed up your algorithm.

Comment: It is a LinkedList class but I'm not sure I know what you mean by retainAll

Comment: It may be a linked list, but I doubt it's a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: OK, retainAll is actually defined in AbstractCollection.  I haven't looked at the code myself; it may well be similar to what you've already written.

Comment: A lot has to do with the presumed length of the lists.  If they are only maybe 10 elements long then the above code is pretty good.  But if they both get into hundreds or thousands of elements you want to avoid the N-squared performance of your nested loops.  There are various ways to do this, depending on the anticipated size -- score card, sorted lists, hash tables.  (As Dawood suggests, if the lists are already sorted you can basically compare next elements and get it pretty close to order-N.)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution In Question:** You are using two `for` loop and comparing items of each list to other list item. As a result the solution is O(n^2).

**Optimized solution:** Instead of comparing you can use `HashMap`, then insert one lists items into it using O(n) complexity.

Then using a loop check whether the items present in `HashMap`, the second loop also have O(n) complexity.

So, the complexity of the solution will be O(N) + O(N).

> Please check the final solution:

```
public static LLList intersect(LLList list1, LLList list2) {
    LLList inters = new LLList();

    Map<LLList, Integer> list1Map = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
       list1Map.put(list1.getItem(i), 1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
       if(list1Map[list1.getItem(i)] == 1) {
          inters.addItem(list1.getItem(i)], inters.length());
       }
    }

    return inters;
}
```

Comment: You could just use `HashSet` instead of `HashMap` for this.  Also, I think your `if` condition should be `if (list1Map.get(list2.getItem(i)) == 1)`.  Of course, if you change to a `HashSet` that would be `if (list1Set.contains(list2.getItem(i)))`.

Comment: There's no reason to have the redundant `<LLList, Integer>`; I'm not sure why you keep adding it back.